# VSCode - Is VSCode suitable and compatible for developing also with Angular JS (angular 1)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is VSCode suitable and compatible for developing also with Angular JS (angular 1) ? Is there something needed to do in VSCode to make it more friendly for developing with Angular JS, like for example use some recommended extensions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, VSCode is suitable and compatible for developing Angular 1.x projects.
Have a look at the extension [gallery](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery). There are many useful extensions available.

Comment: can u pls recommend some specific useful extensions for this purpose ?

Comment: This depends on your workflow, but Debugger for Chrome is a very helpful plugin. You can search on your own at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/VSCode